# Is there a better way to get number of threads per block is my way is correct and bug free?

Tags: cuda

I was looking for on the internet for a official way to get the maximum number of threads per block for the current NVIDIA GPU and I found nothing.

I was read that the number must be 2^N so I did some code that find it but I am not sure that it is 100% correct and maybe there is a better way.

In my case it give me the output 1024 (for my NVIDIA GTX 660M).

This is my code:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>




// Easy print macros:
#define pp std::cout <<
#define ss << " " <<
#define ee << std::endl;
#define ww while(1){Sleep(100);} return 0;



namespace nameMyCudaSystem {

    int threadsPerBlock = 0;


    __global__ void ThreadPerBlockCounter(){/*Do nothing*/}


    int InitializeCuda()
    {
        cudaError_t cudaStatus;


        // Choose which GPU to run on, change this on a multi-GPU system.
        cudaStatus = cudaSetDevice(0);
        if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) return -1;


        threadsPerBlock = 1;
        do
        {
            if (threadsPerBlock > 1)
            {
                cudaStatus = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
                if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess)
                {
                    return -2;
                    break;
                }
            }
            threadsPerBlock *= 2;
            ThreadPerBlockCounter << <1, threadsPerBlock >> >();
        } while (cudaGetLastError() == cudaSuccess);

        threadsPerBlock /= 2;

        if (threadsPerBlock == 0) return -3;

        return 0;

    }



}






int main()
{

    if (nameMyCudaSystem::InitializeCuda() != 0) return -1; // error (some error inside InitializeCuda)

    pp nameMyCudaSystem::threadsPerBlock ee; // print the maximum number of thread per block

    ww; // just a loop to keep the console window open...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The CUDA API includes functions that will calculate block size that will achieve maximum occupancy. And no that isn't anything like correct. The block size should usually be a multiple of 32, not a power of 2.

Comment: What function from this API will give me the amount of threads per block?

Comment: Read the second answer in the marked duplicate

Comment: Where is the second answer? I did not found it.
Anyway I just found my answer here: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15668-s11/www/cuda-doc/html/group__CUDART__DEVICE_g5aa4f47938af8276f08074d09b7d520c.html

Thank you

Comment: Scroll down and read everything

Comment: I found now this second answer. thank you.
sorry for the duplicate..

Comment: There are about 11000 CUDA questions here. it is very likely that what you want to ask had been asked before. Searching is always preferable